# docker - connect over http to running container

Tags: docker

I have created a docker image from the following Docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN echo "Europe/London" > /etc/timezone
RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata 

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -q -y install lsof
RUN apt-get install net-tools
RUN apt-get install psmisc
RUN apt-get -y install curl

RUN rm -Rf /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/logs/
RUN touch /etc/nginx/logs/error.log

RUN mkdir /usr/share/nginx/logs/
RUN touch /usr/share/nginx/logs/error.log

ADD ./conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

ADD supervisor.nginx.conf /etc/supervisor.d/nginx.conf

copy ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html/

EXPOSE 80
CMD /usr/bin/supervisord -n
```

I then built the image  with:

`docker build -t dnginx .`

I then created a container with:

```
docker run --name d3 -d -p 80:80 dnginx
```

I can see the container is running and port 80 is exposed by running docker ps -a:

```
42ba6aa343bd        dnginx              "/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin"   2 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   d3
```

I can find out the IP address by running `docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' d3`

But I cannot connect to the container if try and hit the url from the IP address:

`curl http://172.17.0.2` I get the following response

> Failed to connect to 127.17.0.2 port 80: Operation timed out

I cannot ping the ip address either

What have I missed out?

Comment: Run `docker exec -it d3 bash` and check the status of nginx inside the container. We cannot see anything without the configuration files.

Comment: I can see that nginx is runing and when I curl localhost from insde the container, I get an html response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `docker run --name d3 -d -p 80:80 dnginx` means that you map port 80 on your host computer to port 80 in your docker container.

You can see the mapping in the `docker ps` output as `0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp`

This way if you `curl 127.0.0.1` or `curl your-ip-here` on your host computer, your request is automatically routed to the nginx container which will serve the traffic.

There's no need to lookup container's private IP. You can use any of your host computer's IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Get the docker-machine ip and use to access your nginx

`docker-machine ls` < Show  your(s) docker(s)-machine(s)

See the name of the machine you want to access, and:

`docker-machine ip <name>` < Show IP address if your docker-machine

Try access your nignx using this IP